# Scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor Rules and callback giving some headache

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to do:

```
class SpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "lolies"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.domain.com/directory/lol2']
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'directory/lol2/\w+$']), follow=True), Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'directory/lol2/\w+/\d+$']), follow=True),Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'directory/lol2/\d+$']), callback=self.parse_loly))

def parse_loly(self, response):
    print 'Hi this is the loly page %s' % response.url
    return
```

That returns me:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

If I change callback to `callback="self.parse_loly"` seems never to be called and print the URL.

But seems to be crawling the sites with no problems because I get many Crawled 200 debug messages for that rule.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the whitespace for `parse_loly` is not aligned correctly. Python is whitespace sensitive so to the interpreter it looks like a method outside of SpiderSpider.

You might also want to split your rules line into shorter lines as per [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).

Try this:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class SpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "lolies"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.domain.com/directory/lol2/']
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\w+$', ))), 
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\w+/\d+$', ))),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\d+$',)), callback='parse_loly'),
    )

    def parse_loly(self, response):
        print 'Hi this is the loly page %s' % response.url
        return None
```

Comment: Sorry, I left a few extra characters in there that I have since removed. Is it the same error message?

Comment: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Okay. I think I've got it - I read through the tutorials on [the scrapy docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html) and found that you'll want to call the method by referring to it as a string, in this case `'parse_loly'`. I've also optimized some of the other code as per their example - such as using the start_url as the base for the rule allowances.

Comment: Also if you don't have a callback, ``follow = True`` is the default behavior.

Comment: OK! Got it solved. Needed to move the rule with callback over the other rules because if not finds a match before... Just thought about it and it worked ;)... Thanks!